# How to fix group by and order by year and months in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm trying to fix the order by and group by year and month format. This is my sql query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y %b") ym 
FROM `book_summaries` 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y %b") 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y %b")
```

But the sql query result is this:

```
2018 Apr
2018 Aug
2018 Dec
2018 Feb
2018 Jul
2018 Jun
2018 Mar
2018 May
2018 Nov
2018 Oct
2018 Sep
2019 Apr
2019 Aug
2019 Dec
```

It seems that only the year format has been ordered but not the months in it. How can I alter my query to order by `year` and then `months`?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Looks like DATE_FORMAT returns character values, since you result is in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `order by` the minimum date in each range:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y %b') ym 
FROM `book_summaries` 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y %b') 
ORDER BY MIN(created_at);
```

Note that I also replaced the double quotes with single quotes.  Single quotes are the SQL standard for strings (although some database do support double quotes as a string delimiter).